# Getting an error in useQueries in React Query

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have an array in the React app, and the api has to call for each value. I am using `react-query` and I think I can use `useQueries` for this situation. But I get an error. Or how can I get a data for each request? You can give me another solution.

My request function

```
export function useTableStatusUseQueries({ from, to, stepTypes }) {
  const results = useQueries({
    queries: stepTypes?.map((type) => ({
      queryKey: [QUERY_KEYS.tableStatus, type, from, to],
      queryFn: axiosInstance.get('/reports/table/status', {
        params: {
          from: moment(from).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
          to: to !== 'Invalid date' ? moment(to).format('YYYY-MM-DD') : moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
          stepType: type,
        },
      }),
    })),
  });
  return results;
}
```

In Component

```
  const { data: queriesData } = useTableStatusUseQueries({
    from: moment(dateRange[0]).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    to: moment(dateRange[1]).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    stepTypes: ['CREATE_DISPOSAL', 'FINAL_DOCUMENT'],
  });

  console.log(queriesData);
```

I get this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: queries.map is not a function
```

The api has to call twice

one of them is `https://localhost:3000/reports/table/status?stepType=CREATE_DISPOSAL`
another one is `https://localhost:3000/reports/table/status?stepType=FINAL_DOCUMENT`

Comment: Why an optional after stepTypes? Is it always an array or is it sometimes undefined? If it’s undefined, that would explain the error message

Comment: @AdamJenkins yeah It can be undefined. It is an example for understanding and will be dynamic with usestate, if I find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found my own problem. The problem is syntax. I have written wrong way.

The correct syntax is

```
export function useTableStatusUseQueries({ from, to, stepTypes }) {
  return useQueries(
    stepTypes?.map((type) => ({
      queryKey: [QUERY_KEYS.tableStatus, type, from, to],
      queryFn: () =>
        axiosInstance.get('/reports/table/status', {
          params: {
            from: moment(from).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
            to: to !== 'Invalid date' ? moment(to).format('YYYY-MM-DD') : moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
            stepType: type,
          },
        }),
    })),
  );
}
```

in component

```
  const queriesData = useTableStatusUseQueries({
    from: moment(dateRange[0]).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    to: moment(dateRange[1]).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    stepTypes: ['CREATE_DISPOSAL', 'FINAL_DOCUMENT'],
  });

  console.log(queriesData);
```